# Page tab is not loading properly after refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am able to load the **last current page tab** after page refresh. My real purpose is this. 
But after refresh, when i click on another tab, these happens: 
1. non-active tab becomes active nicely (that's what i wanted),
2. The tab becomes active, **page position scrolls down by itself.**
Note that this problem started after adding functions i commented below.

This is my JS file.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#firstTab a').on('click', function(e)){
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).tab('show');
   },onClickEventFunction1());
   $('#secondTab a').on('click', function(e)){
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).tab('show');
   },onClickEventFunction2());
   //problem starts after here
   $("ul.nav-pills-homepage > li > a").on("shown.bs.tab", function (e) {
       var id = $(e.target).attr("href").substr(1);
       window.location.hash = id;
   });
   var hash = window.location.hash;
   $('#myTabs a[href="' + hash + '"]').tab('show');
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try `e.preventDefault();` on the `click` handlers

Comment: Tried e.preventdefault, can you share any additional link for advanced research ?

Comment: It prevents current event from happening. You have it on `load` event. Try putting into `click` event (which doesn't appear in the code you shared)

Comment: @JNF I updated the post , but same thing keeps happening. Even when i added / removed onClickEventFunction1() and onClickEventFunction2()

Comment: Can you take the HTML and javascript to [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) and try to recreate the issue there? It would make it easier to understand